# Alphanumeric sort on first first three chars in the JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I wanted to sort the JSON object specific key values of first three characters.

**Below is the sample JSON format**

```
var obj = [{
id :12,
trackingNo: 'APQW123'},
{
id :13,
trackingNo: '123ABXU'},
{
id :12,
trackingNo: '98012JIH'},
{
id :12,
trackingNo: 'JHG567'}
];
```

**In above object, based on first three chars of trackingNo need to sort the object. trackingNo is combination of alphanumeric.**

I tried the below method. I thought it is numeric sort.It not correct one for this alphanumeric.

```
function sortObject(obj) {
  var sortedData = obj.sort(function (a, b) {

    return a.trackingNo > b.trackingNo;

  });

  return sortedData;
}
```

Could anyone please provide the logic to implement the alphanumeric sort based on first three characters in jasscript.

Comment: What is your expected output? After sorting, are you expecting `123ABXU` to be the first element, or `APQW123` ?

Comment: For `98012JIH` do you want 1st 3 character `JIH` or start sequence `980`?

Comment: I wanted to sort the first three chars of tackingNo in both ascending and decending order. In both directions the Numeric values will come first. For Example '123ABXU'

Comment: in *descending* sort, the numbers goes first, like  `980`, `123`? or ascending?

Answer (score 4):

You could slice the first characters for sorting.

For checking if the value is not a number, a check for `isNaN` is included. Numbers are sorted first and then the other characters.

```js
function sortTrackingNo(array, order) {
    return array.sort(order === 'DESC'
        ? function (b, a) {
            a = a.trackingNo.slice(0, 3);
            b = b.trackingNo.slice(0, 3);
            return isNaN(b) - isNaN(a) || a > b || -(a < b);
        }
        : function (a, b) {
            a = a.trackingNo.slice(0, 3);
            b = b.trackingNo.slice(0, 3);
            return isNaN(a) - isNaN(b) || a > b || -(a < b);
        });
}

var array = [{ id: 12, trackingNo: 'APQW123' }, { id: 13, trackingNo: '123ABXU' }, { id: 12, trackingNo: '98012JIH' }, { id: 12, trackingNo: 'JHG567' }];

sortTrackingNo(array);
console.log(array);

sortTrackingNo(array, 'DESC');
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for your help. Could you please provide logic to implement alphanumeric sort in both ascending  and descending order.

Comment: how should the functtion look like? hardcoded with with `trackingNo` as sort key? or completely dynamic with a given key and an order?

Comment: Provided JSON one is sample format. The object will be the dynamic but key (trackingNo) is the sort key. Values for trackingNo are dynamic with combination of alphanumeric. In both directions the Numeric values need to come first

Comment: Thanks Nina for your help.

Comment: @Kaiido, to get the numerical part, because this items should be sorted on top. with a check with `isNaN`, a following letter after numbers gets `true`, which means the value is not a number.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes I only got it after I posted my comment, sorry.